# vue js Cannot read property 'data' of undefined*

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to vue js.

**this.comments.unshift(response.body.data); is not working.**

I did not use json() like **this.comments.unshift(response.json().data);** and **this.comments = response.json().data;** because using json() does not show any comments. I just searched and someone mentioned to use 'body' instead of json().

Saving a comment in database is working. Only problem is showing a new comment is not working without refresh page.

These are error messages

*[Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined*

Thank you very much.

```
<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            comments: [],
            body: null
        }
    },
    props: {
        postid: null
    },
    methods: {
        getComments () {
            this.$http.get('/blog/' + this.postid+ '/comments').then((response) => {                    
                this.comments = response.body.data;
            });
        },
        createComment () {
            this.$http.post('/blog/' + this.postid+ '/comments', {
                body: this.body
            }).then((response) => {
            //  console.log(this.body);
                this.comments.unshift(response.body.data);
                this.body = null;
            });
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        this.getComments();
    }   }

</script>
```

Comment: If you log `response.body` what comes back?

Comment: console.log(response.body); gives Object {data: Object} data
:
Object
body
:
"ttttttttttttttttt"
created_at
:
"2017-05-30 02:43:32"
created_at_human
:
"1 second ago"
id
:
15
user_id
:
1

Comment: You've checked `console.log(response.body)` inside `getComments`, right? This is where you need to check it.